# Each element of $G$ is a product of two elements of $A$.

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a finite group. $A$ is a subset of $G$. I need to show that if $|A|>\frac{|G|}{2}$ then each element of $G$ is a product of two elements of A.

My working is : the subgroup generated by A must be G, by Lagrange theorem. But how do I estimate the set $\{xy|x,y\in A\}$.

Comment: What is $A$? Can you provide more context and some working of your own?

Comment: This was a Putnam Contest problem, circa 1971.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $g^{-1}A\cap A^{-1}\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Or even faster, $gA^{-1}\cap A\ne \emptyset.$

Answer (score 0):

Just a few details to flesh out Hagen von Eitzen's elegant ***Hint***:

Take

$A^{-1} = \{a^{-1}, \; a \in A \}, \tag 1$

that is, $A^{-1}$ is the set of inverses of the elements of $A$; as such, it is clear that

$\vert A^{-1} \vert = \vert A \vert > \dfrac{\vert G \vert}{2}; \tag 2$

furthermore, for any

$g \in G, \tag 3$

the mapping

$A \to g^{-1}A, \; A \ni a \mapsto g^{-1}a \in g^{-1}A \tag 4$

is both one-to-one and onto; onto since

$a \mapsto g^{-1}a, \; \forall g^{-1}a \in g^{-1}A, \tag 5$

and one-to-one by virtue of

$g^{-1}a_1 = g^{-1}a_2 \Longrightarrow a_1 = ea_1 = (gg^{-1})a_1 = g(g^{-1}a_1)$
$= g(g^{-1}a_2) = (gg^{-1})a_2 = ea_2 = a_2, \tag 6$

where

$e \in G \tag 7$

is the identity element.  Since $a \to g^{-1}a$ is both one-to-one and onto

$\vert g^{-1}A \vert = \vert A \vert > \dfrac{\vert G \vert}{2}; \tag 8$

now (2) and (8) together imply Hagen von Eitzen's insight

$g^{-1}A \cap A^{-1} \ne \emptyset, \tag 9$

using the elementary fact

$\vert B \cup C \vert + \vert B \cap C \vert = \vert B \vert + \vert C \vert, \tag{10}$

which holds for any two finite sets $B$ and $C$; applying this equation to $g^{-1}A$ and $A^{-1}$ yields

$\vert g^{-1}A  \cup A^{-1} \vert + \vert g^{-1}A \cap A^{-1} \vert = \vert g^{-1}A \vert + \vert A^{-1} \vert; \tag{11}$

but

$\vert g^{-1}A  \cup A^{-1} \vert \le \vert G \vert, \tag{12}$

since

$g^{-1}A \cup A^{-1} \subset G, \tag{13}$

and the right-hand side of (11) is greater than $\vert G \vert$ by (2) and (8); thus $\vert g^{-1}A \cap A^{-1} \vert > 0$ and (9) follows directly.

Having (9) at our disposal for any $g \in G$, we see there are

$a, b \in A \tag{14}$

such that

$g^{-1}a = b^{-1}, \tag{15}$

whence an easy re-arrangement yields

$g = ab, \tag{16}$

the desired result.